# Populating a 2D Array with random integers

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int ourArray [3][5] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            ourArray [i][j] = rand() % 30;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I've got so far, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here. What I (think) is going on here is it goes to first position of the array at 0,0 and generates a number. Then it goes to 1,1 and 2,2 and so on. I'm not sure where to go from there, and I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this that populates an entire row or column at a time.

Additionally, my compiler won't allow me to use cout or endl like I normally can? It's insisting I use std::cout and I was just wondering why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I (think) is going on here is it goes to first position of the array at 0,0 and generates a number. Then it goes to 1,1 and 2,2 and so on.

The array positions are filled in this order:

```
i = 0, j = 0,4

0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4

i = 1, j = 0,4

1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4

i = 2, j = 0,4

2, 0
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
2, 4
```

There isn't any more efficient way to fill the entire array with random numbers.

In order to use `cout` and `endl`, you have to include `iostream` in your file:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Then, you can either use them with `std::` prefix, `std::cout` and `std::endl`. If you don't wish to use the `std::` prefix, you have to indicate that you are using the `std` namespace by:

```
using namespace std;
```